# Excel VBA: How to change the ChartType of an individual series?

Tags: excel, vba

This may seem like a simple question with an obvious answer, but all my attempts so far have been in vain! What am I doing wrong?

**I have a combo chart with multiple series and chart types, and want to programatically change the 'ChartType' of the first two data series using VBA. How can I make this work?**

---

[image: Change Chart Type]

---

The latest iteration of VBA code I'm trying to use:

This code is very similar to what I'd get if recording a macro and changing the series chart type manually, yet it always fails when I try to run the macro myself.
[Selection_ChartType] is a named cell linked to a radio (option) button on the same sheet.

```
Sub ChartTypeSelect()
Dim slct As Integer

slct = [Selection_ChartType]

Call DisableUpdates

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Q_Hist").ChartObjects("Chart_Q_Hist")
    If slct = 1 Then
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnStacked    ' Run-time error '438' happens here
        .FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ElseIf slct = 2 Then
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlAreaStacked      ' Run-time error '438' happens here
        .FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlAreaStacked
    End If
End With

Call EnableUpdates
End Sub
```

Run-time error '438': (Object doesn't support this property or method)

---

P.S. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Q_Hist").ChartObjects("Chart_Q_Hist").Select`  correctly selects the intended chart, so I'd assume I'm referencing the object correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FullSeriesCollection` is a property of a `Chart`, not a `ChartObject`. Basically, a `ChartObject` is a container for a `Chart`, and that chart is available via the property `Chart`:

So try

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Q_Hist").ChartObjects("Chart_Q_Hist").Chart
```

Comment: Bingo!  Knew it was probably going to be something 'simple', but didn't realise I needed to go deeper into the chart object.  Thank you very much.